# Как запретить пустой CharField

Tags: python, django

Допустим, есть какая-то модель с полем CharField

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
```

Вообще такие поля по умолчанию имеют атрибуты `null=False` и `blank=False`. Это учитывается при отрисовке форм, например. Но если создам экземпляр модели прямо в коде и не передам в конструктор какое-то из этих полей, оно примет значение пустой строки и создастся.

```py
p = Product(name='Test')
print(p.description) # Напечатается '', оно же создастся в базе при сохранении
```

Что с этим делать? Как запретить создание экземпляра модели, если обязательное поле не передали в конструктор? Переопределять save и проверять там что-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы можно сделать валидацию в модели? [Ссылка на документацию с примерами](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)

В вашем случае код может выглядеть примерно так:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def clean(self):
        if self.description == '':
            raise ValidationError('Description required.')
```

Как я понял, если работаете с `ModelForm`, то оно само выполнит валидацию, в остальных случаях нужно вызывать вручную:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


p = Product(name='Test')

try:
    p.full_clean()
except ValidationError as e:
    # Ошибки хранятся в e.message_dict.
    print(e.message_dict)
```

**Update.** Еще возможное решение. Попробуйте добавить `min_length=1` в параметры `CharField`, тогда, может быть, нельзя будет создать пустое поле. Проверить сам не могу.

```
description = models.CharField(max_length=400, min_length=1)
```